# How can I use a c# variable in jquery?

Tags: c#, jquery, sql, webforms

I have a project that I am going to call image paths from SQL. I have tested placing the variable in the image source

HTML

```
<li><a href='"<%=img_src_path%>"'><img src='"<%=img_src_path%>"' id="myImage" runat="server" alt="" title=""/></a></li>
```

Code Behind

```
myImage.src = "imagePage";
```

Is this same thing possible with javascript? here is my jquery:

```
 $("#fancybox-manual-c").click(function () {
            $.fancybox.open([
                {
                    href: '1_b.jpg',
                    title: 'My title'
                }, {
                    href: '2_b.jpg',
                    title: '2nd title'
                }, {
                    href: '3_b.jpg'
                }
            ], {
                helpers: {
                    thumbs: {
                        width: 75,
                        height: 50
                    }
                }
            });
```

Is it now possible to put the value of `myImage` in place of the actual images listed here in the jQuery

Comment: You're missing a layer of information here: is this an ASP.NET page? ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: You can set the image source dynamically via javascript/jQuery, but no need to put the variable in the html markup.

Comment: this is an asp.net page. simple webform

Comment: @MichaelWheeler how is this done?

Comment: Jquery has a function called `.attr()` that can get or set the href, src, or other attributes of an element. See my answer below for a simple implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use `<%= %>` syntax in JavaScript to inject server variables into your code:

```
 $("#fancybox-manual-c").click(function () {
    $.fancybox.open([
        {
            href: '<%= img_src_path_1 >',
            title: 'My title'
        }, {
            href: '<%= img_src_path_2 >',
            title: '2nd title'
        }, {
            href: '<%= img_src_path_3 >'
        }
    ], {
        helpers: {
            thumbs: {
                width: 75,
                height: 50
            }
        }
    });
});
```

You could also access the `src` property of any image on your page with jQuery:

```
$("#myImage").prop("src");
```

---

But, there is some weirdness in your code:

1. You are setting the img src twice.  Once with `<%= %>` in the HTML and again in the code behind with `myImage.src = "imagePath";`.  Why?
2. You are double quoting your HTML attributes.  Use single quotes or double quotes, but not both on a single attribute.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not familiar with fancybox, but this is how I would use jQuery to do the basic idea.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    img_path = "/the_new_img_path.jpg"
    $("#img_link").attr("href", img_path)
    $("#img").attr("src", img_path)
})
```

Then in the HTML

```
<a href='/some_default_link' id='img_link'><img id='my_img' src='/some_default_image.jpg' /></a>
```

Comment: The img path comes from SQL, whereas you have it hard coded.  I think Skullomania is looking for how to get the values from SQL into the JavaScript.

Comment: Oh, I was under the impression the filename would be gathered dynamically via an xmlhttprequest or something, rather than only once on page load. If it is only on page load, it seems Javascript would not be necessary

Comment: lol.  There was a time when no one knew how to do anything with AJAX.  Now it seems no one knows how to do anything *without* AJAX.

Comment: Okay, I'll go back to the PHP tag where I belong :(